# Add bccAddresses to SingleEmailMessage

Tags: singleemailmessage

I'm trying to send an email and to add some bcc addresses to it.

I don't get an error, I even get the debug statement:
"The 1st email was sent successfully." and the email is sent to the email main recipient (i.e. the 'To'). and yet, the email isn't being sent to the bcc addresses.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.ToAddresses = new String[] {msg.FromAddress};

message.bccAddresses = new String[] {};
message.bccAddresses.add('mytestemail1@gmail.com');
message.bccAddresses.add('mytestemail2@gmail.com');
message.setPlainTextBody(body);

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > {message};
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
if (results[0].success) {
    System.debug('The 1st email was sent successfully.');
} else {
    System.debug('The 1st email failed to send: ' + results[0].errors[0].message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the set methods as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm).

```
message.setBccAddresses(new String[]{'mytestemail1@gmail.com','mytestemail2@gmail.com'});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure if this would be an issue but bccAddresses is a `List<String>` and not a `String []`.
2. Also this can be an issue as per the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm)...

   > If the BCC compliance option is set at the organization ​level, the user cannot add BCC addresses on standard messages. The following error code is returned: BCC_NOT_ALLOWED_IF_BCC_ COMPLIANCE_​ENABLED. ​Contact your Salesforce representative for information on BCC compliance.